# Error running Spatial Autocorrelation (Moran´s I)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, autocorrelation, moran-index

I am trying to run the Moran´s I, but the ArcMap keeps sending the message in the picture below. I am trying to analyze spatial autocorrelation of some socioeconomic data in neighbourhoods in a city (Belo Horizonte, Brazil). The database is neighbourhood data downloaded from a public database joined with other data I gathered in an Excel spreadsheet.

Funny thing is that last week I ran tests with some of the variables and it worked. When I tried to run for real now it is not working. Now even when I download again the original database, the same error appears (and no, I am not checking the report box). The error message is the one below:

> Messages Executing: SpatialAutocorrelation Compilados POPULACAO NO_REPORT INVERSE_DISTANCE EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE NONE # # Start Time: Mon Nov 13 19:41:16 2023 Running script SpatialAutocorrelation... Failed script SpatialAutocorrelation...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\MoransI.py", line 610, in setupGlobalI() File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\MoransI.py", line 72, in setupGlobalI ssdo = SSDO.SSDataObject(inputFC, useChordal = True) File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSDataObject.py", line 321, in init useChordalDistances = self.useChordal) File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSUtilities.py", line 3149, in init self.setInfo() File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSUtilities.py", line 3175, in setInfo info = distanceUnitInfo[self.name] KeyError: u'M'
>
> Failed to execute (SpatialAutocorrelation). Failed at Mon Nov 13 19:41:16 2023 (Elapsed Time: 0,19 seconds)

[image]